# How to properly represent "leave unchanged"

Tags: forms, password, password-change

Users can edit various information, it's all in the same modal (including the password).

What would be the best way to represent to the user "leave blank to remain unchanged" (referring to passwords).

The idea is that a user can edit the email (among other info) but may not want to change the password - they should be able to update all other info (including the password) but only if they want to.

Answer (score 1):

Simply place **helper text** around input field "leave blank to remain unchanged".

[image: helper text in material design]
[image: helper text in Boottsarp]

It is better to define separate user journey for update password functionality for **simplicity**.

Even with the **security** concern passwords are kept separately in database.

I will suggest to separate password-update from the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Display  (Unchanged) in light-gray text in the text area. Handle focus and edit events to set the text to blank/regular color when focused, and remove the "Unchanged" status if actual text gets entered. Switch back to (Unchanged)/light gray when losing focus.

Usually painfully difficult, but this is the right way. What is easy and what is right separates the pros from the amateurs.

Wrap the implmentation in a control so you can re-use it again. You will.